# How to characterize the closed sets in a subspace?

Tags: general-topology

We know that the subspace topology of $Y \subset (X, \mathfrak{T})$ is given by

$$\mathfrak{T}_Y = \{Y \cap U | U \in \mathfrak{T}\}$$

Then it occurred to me that take any open set from the subspace topology:

$$O = Y \cap U $$

Then the closed set would be:

$$O^c = Y^c \cup U^c = C $$ where $C$ is a closed set in $X$

Can someone explain why the closed sets in the subspace are:

$\{Y \cap C | C \text{ closed in }  X\}$, instead of just $C$ as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closed subset of $Y$ (in the subspace topology) is the complement *in $Y$* of an open subset of $Y$. So you want to take the complement of $O$ in $Y$, not in $X$. Given an open set $O=Y \cap U$ of $Y$, its complement in $Y$ is
\begin{align*}
Y \setminus O&= Y \cap O^c\\ &=Y \cap (Y \cap U)^c\\& =Y \cap (Y^c \cup U^c)\\&=(Y \cap Y^c) \cup (Y \cap U^c)\\&=Y \cap U^c\\&=Y\cap C
\end{align*}
where $C$ is a closed set in $X$.